# Sorting a list of string to show first strings with a particular substring and then the remaining strings in their sorted order

Tags: java, comparator

I have a list of string (com.abc.c345, com.abc.a123, com.abc.d456, com.abc.b234, com.qwr.a1, com.wer.b2, com.ert.c3)

I want to sort this so that the strings containing 'com.abc' will be displayed first in their sorted style and after that the remaining strings in their sorted style.

So the output should look something like this

(com.abc.a123, com.abc.b234, com.abc.c345, com.abc.d456, com.ert.c3, com.qwr.a1, com.wer.b2)

Edit 1:
I tried using comparators as:

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<LoggerDetails>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(LoggerDetails o1, LoggerDetails o2) {
            if (o1.logger.startsWith("com.abc") && o2.logger.startsWith("com.abc")) {
                return o1.logger.compareTo(o2.logger);
            }
            if (o1.logger.startsWith("com.abc") && !o2.logger.startsWith("com.abc")) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o1.logger.startsWith("com.abc") && !o2.logger.startsWith("com.abc")) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: `com` is common for all?

Comment: 'com.abc' is the common substring based on which I have to sort. The remaining entries can start with anything.

Comment: What options have you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried using comparators but didn't work

Comment: @Sanket: what did the comparators look like? And what exactly does "didn't work" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close: use your comparator, which performs ordering according to first criterion, then compound it with natural ordering comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<LoggerDetails>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(LoggerDetails o1, LoggerDetails o2) {
        if(o1.logger.startsWith("com.abc") && !o1.logger.startsWith("com.abc")) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o1.logger.startsWith("com.abc") && !o1.logger.startsWith("com.abc")) {
            return -1;
        } -- I just copypasted your original code, this should definitely be vice versa
        return 0;
    }  
}.thenComparing(o -> o.logger, Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

You can make your comparator more concise utilizing fact than booleans are comparable:

```
comparing(o -> o.logger.startsWith("com.abc"), Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Or if you have more such "exceptional" strings (as I noticed you are keeping editing original post), map them onto numbers.

Comment: I tried this but my endpoint is giving me this error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

Comment: I don't think you want the same if with the same result twice, you're missing the `return 1` case.

Comment: It means sorting algorithm is confused of what is less than, equal and greater than based on data provided by your comparator. Fix your if - return code or use comparison using functions.

Comment: It worked, I had some other problem in my code. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

create a new list by removing every entry starting with your substring and add it to a new list.

after that you can just add the elements of the new list using list.addAll(0, newList)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply sort the list using Collections.sort provided in util package in java. Your desired output seems to be in alphabetical and numerically sorted format, so that would work. Here is the code sample that worked for me:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("com.abc.c345");
    list.add("com.abc.a123");
    list.add("com.abc.d456");
    list.add("com.abc.b234");
    list.add("com.qwr.a1");
    list.add("com.wer.b2");
    list.add("com.ert.c3");

    Collections.sort(list);
    list.forEach(value -> System.out.println(value));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: 'com.abc' is a dummy value so this won't work. Actual value is something else.

Comment: can you provide a sample set of input for more clarity.. I can see com.qwr and com.ert also in your question, so what do you mean by dummy